# Stuck on moving paddle

Tags: java, netbeans-8

For my class I need to create a one player pong game. We need to use what we've learned so its simple code and the problem is, while the "while loop" is running, my Keydown thread doesn't seem to work. My teacher isn't helpful at all so that's why i'm here. Please help by only using methods and such that are used in my program.

I've tried moving the ball code into a run thread but i can never seem to actually get that thread running.

```java
public class PongGame extends Applet {

    int startup = 0;
    int x = 400;
    int y = 500;
    int x2 = (int) (Math.random() * (600 + 1));
    int y2 = (int) (Math.random() * (600 + 1));
    int xVelocity = 1;
    int yVelocity = 1;
    int x2Velocity = 1;
    int y2Velocity = 1;
    int curry = 700;
    int currx = 600;
    int counter = 2;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(1440, 900);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 36));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(Event evt, int key) {

        startup = startup + 1;
        repaint();

        if (key == Event.RIGHT) {
            currx += 10;
        }
        if (key == Event.LEFT) {
            currx -= 10;
        }

        if (currx == 1400) {
            currx = 10;
        }
        if (currx == 20) {
            currx = 1399;
        }

        repaint();
        return false;

    }

    public void run(Graphics g) {
        startup = 0;
        while (counter > 0) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            x += xVelocity;
            y += yVelocity;

            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(currx, curry, 300, 25);

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);

            for (int j = 0; j < 20000000; j++);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);

            //Bounce the ball off the wall or paddle
            if (x >= 1400 || x <= 0) {
                xVelocity = -xVelocity;
            }
            if (y >= 800 || y <= 0) {
                yVelocity = -yVelocity;
            }
            if (((y == 675)) && ((currx <= x) && (currx + 300) >= x)) {
                yVelocity = -yVelocity;
                y = y - 10;
                repaint();

            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (startup == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("Welcome To PONG", 0, 100);
            g.drawString("Created by Caden Anton", 0, 200);
            g.drawString("copyright May 3rd, 2019 ©", 0, 300);
            g.drawString("Press any key to continue", 0, 400);
        }

        if (startup == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("RULES:", 0, 100);
            g.drawString("Press the arrwow keys to move the paddle", 0, 200);
            g.drawString("Your objective is to keep the ball from touching the ground", 0, 300);
            g.drawString("Once the ball hits the ground you lose the game", 0, 400);
        }
        if (startup >= 2) {
            //Input Run thread start here. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a KeyListener, look at [this example](https://way2java.com/awt-events/applet-tutorial-keyboard-input-key-event-keylistener/).

Comment: 2019... `Applet`... oh gosh...